# Exclude member-only content on HTML Sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I've used the basic HTML sitemap code from Yoast. Wondering if it's possible to exclude member-only pages and posts.

```
<h2 id="pages">Pages</h2>
<ul>
<?php
// Add pages you'd like to exclude in the exclude here
wp_list_pages( array( 'exclude' => '', 'title_li' => '') );
?>
</ul>
<h2 id="posts">Blog Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
// Add categories you'd like to exclude in the exclude here
$cats = get_categories('exclude=');
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  echo "<li><h3>".$cat->cat_name."</h3>";
  echo "<ul>";
  query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat='.$cat->cat_ID);
  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $category = get_the_category();
    // Only display a post link once, even if it's in multiple categories
    if ($category[0]->cat_ID == $cat->cat_ID) {
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you checked [the FAQ](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/faq/) or [the plugin's support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-seo)?

Comment: Your answer is not related to my question at all. I'm not using yoast plugins, simply credited him for the code above, picked up at https://yoast.com/html-sitemap-wordpress/

Comment: How do you define what a member page/post is?

Comment: If for "member-only pages and posts" you mean posts marked as "private" in backend, that posts/pages are auto-excluded if the person viewing sitemap is not logged. If you want to hide the also for logged users, use the argument `post_status=publish` Also, please, even if Yoast does it, **don't** use `query_posts`.

Comment: @czerspalace - For this particular purpose, I need to check if the user is logged in. I'm not sure where to stick that in here.

Comment: @G.M. - What should I use instead of query_posts?

Comment: Clarification: I use Wordpress Access Control to set post visibility by User Role. Right now the Sitemap shows all posts even when the user is not logged in.

Comment: @G.M. This page has nothing but the code above. Per that chart it seems OK to use query_posts, no?

Comment: @Phantasmix that answer is related to **any** query in WordPress. Have you read the bold line on 5th line: **"TL;DR don't use query_posts() ever"**

Comment: @G.M. - Your first comment answered my question. The sitemap DOES exclude pages if the user isn't logged in. Next, I will attempt to rewrite the query without query_posts. Thank you.